# angular + pagination + page resets to 1 on navigation to secondary outlet

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngx-pagination

I have implemented a custom pagination component using `PaginationControlsDirective`.

I have a requirement where in I have to open a dialog component (pop up) as a secondary outlet from the pagination component.
Scenario is:

Have a parent component.

Pagination component is the primary outlet.

Dialog/popup is the secondary outlet.

URL to pagination component: `http://localhost:4200/pricing/quickViewPricing/pricesite?page=2`

Now on a button click, I call `router.navigate` to secondary outlet:

```
this.router.navigate([{ 
   outlets: { fullViewPopup: ‘fullviewprice’ } }], 
   { relativeTo: this.route.parent });
```

Pop up opens with the URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/pricing/quickViewPricing/(pricesite//fullViewPopup:fullviewprice/fullviewpricedetail)
```

`pricesite` is my primary outlet at `quickViewPricing`
`fullViewPopup` is my secondary outlet on `quickViewPricing`

**ISSUE**: When the pop up comes up, the page number is not retained and the page goes back to first page.

**routing.module:**

```
path: 'quickViewPricing',
    component: QuickViewPricingComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: "Pricing - Qucik View Price" },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'pricesite',
        component: QvpPaginationContainerComponent,
        outlet: 'primary',
        canActivate: [DoNotShowSecondaryOnRefreshGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'fullviewprice',
        component: FullViewPriceComponent,
        outlet: 'fullViewPopup',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'fullviewpricedetail',
            component: FullViewPriceDetailComponent
          }
        ]
      }  
    ]
```

**QvpPaginationContainerComponent**
//Event handler on button click

```
public fullViewClick(event) {
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { fullViewPopup: 'fullviewprice' } }], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent });
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

**QvpPaginationContainerComponent.html**

```
<div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: config; let i = index">
    <app-price-site [index]="i" [siteId]="item"></app-price-site>
  </div>
```

**selector app-price-site is a custom pagination component**

1. `QvpPaginationContainerComponent` is the primary outlet with pagination implemented
2. `FullViewPriceComponent` is the secondary outlet and is a dialog which is working fine.

When I navigate to page 2 in `QvpPaginationContainerComponent` and click the button, the pop up comes up but the page gets reset to first page in `QvpPaginationContainerComponent`.

Any help for this is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Sachin , Since this URLs won't work as it is localhost kindly edit your question and provide your code whatever you've done. Regards.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I posted the url's just to highlight how the routing is happening in the browser. Please find the edited question with the code